# About converting the received message from ASCII code to human-readable message in OMNeT++

Tags: c++, std, stdout, omnet++

I sent a 'hello, world' message to a node in OMNeT++through the interface of ext module. I received {104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100} in OMNeT++. I found that this is its ASCII code, so I wrote a conversion program, but this program can convert the ASCII code into a string character string in the dev c++compiler. However, its application in OMNeT++has no effect. The following is the code of the conversion program.

I hope you can help me find out the key to the problem and give suggestions to solve it. Thanks again！！！

```
EV<<"pos="<<pos<<endl;
 std::string new_s = str.substr(pos); // 提取从pos位置到末尾的子串
 char myArray[new_s.size()+1];
 strncpy(myArray, new_s.c_str(),new_s.size()+1);
 myArray[new_s.size()-1]='\0';
std::stringstream test;
     for (int i = 0; i <sizeof(myArray) ; i++) {
        test << myArray[i];
     }
     // 将字符串流转换为字符串类型
std:: string want = test.str();
std::cout << "Received message: " << want << std::endl;
std::string str1(myArray);
 // 输出结果
 EV << str1 << endl;
```

Comment: Could you show the value of `pos` as well as the content of `str`?

Comment: Those numbers are, indeed, the ASCII codes for the characters in `"Hello, world"`. If that's what's in `str`, what's the problem? Looks to me like `new_s` has them. What's the rest of the code trying to do?

Comment: Pos is actually the position of '{' in the string, so the content of my new_s is {104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100}. I'll put new here first_ S becomes a char [] array, and then wants to change its corresponding 'hello, world' through the char [] array. Do you have any good methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you have presented `str` is a `std::string` object that contains "hello, world". So in order to print it, no conversion is required.

To show it in the simulation window:

```
EV << "1 Received message: " << str << std::endl;
```

Result:
[image]

To show it in the console:

```
std::cout << "2 Received message: " << str << std::endl;
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I still can't solve this problem. I print new_ The content of s is still {104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100}. I don't know if it is convenient for you to leave an email. I will send you the details of the problem

Comment: If I understand correctly, `std::cout << str << std::endl;` results in printing: `{104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100}` - is it true?

Comment: Thank you, Jerzy. I have solved my current problem, but now I have a new difficulty. How can I send the message received by the node in the application layer app to the mobility module, and let it move according to the sent location information? Do you have any good methods or suggestions

Comment: Yes, create a new question and provide [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: OK, I have created a new question. Can you help me to look at it

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: Sorry, the previously created issue has been deleted for some reason. Now I have posted a new question and I don't know if you can see it. I hope to get your help. Thank you very much!!!